# Interfacing TM1640 LED driver with 7 segment display and PIC microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, led-driver, microchip, 7segmentdisplay, pic16f

I have a customized LED display in which [AIP1640](https://cdn.velleman.eu/downloads/29/infosheets/aip1640_datasheet.pdf) driver IC mounted on it and I think it's equivalent to [TM1640](https://mikroshop.ch/pdf/tm1640.pdf). So does anyone have a working library for this driver?

I want to interface it with [PIC16F886](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/40001291H.pdf). None of the code available on internet seems to be working for me.

Comment: _"I think its equivalent to_" Please don't. Compare the datasheets and verify.

Comment: Okay I have compared and its euivalent only.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "I have a customized LED display"? You may not need the driver IC.

Comment: No I need this driver since there are 11 digits.

Comment: I would try "bit-banging" a test first.  That is, study the datasheet carefully, and create a routine that toggles SCLK and DIN manually.  May find an oscilloscope or logic analyzer to be very helpful.  Get it to display "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A b."  Once you have that, optimize it and convert to a library if desired.  Note from the datasheet that this chip has two main modes of operation: [command+address+data] (single-character mode), and [command+address+data1+data2+data_n...] (multiple-character mode.)  Either mode may need a final command to turn on the display.

Comment: The serial protocol looks like [I²C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) with the address replaced by commands. :-D However, SPI might work, too, I did not look at the setup and hold times.